# doSignInWithEmailAndPassword() is missing from firebase.auth()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use React Context to provide a firebase instance to my React Application. Firebase class that I wrote is as below:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DB_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
  }

  // *** AUTH API ***

  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };

  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
    this.auth.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };

  doSignOut = () => this.auth.signOut();

  doPasswordReset = email => this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);

  doPasswordUpdate = password => this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password);
}

export default Firebase;
```

When I try to do sign in with Email and Password, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: this.auth.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function
    at Firebase.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword (firebase.js:27)
    at SignInFormBase.onSubmit (SignIn.jsx:26)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:265)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:571)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:596)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:695)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:704)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:676)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:844)
    at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:852)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5030)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21469)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2247)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5110)
    at react-dom.development.js:21526
    at Object.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:255)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21525)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2268)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5086)
```

Anyone could help me figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
    this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };
```

See the reference here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html?authuser=0#signinwithemailandpassword